# GPS Location on Nexus 5

Tags: gps, location

just installed UTouch 14.10 r243 on my Nexus 5.  So far so good, apart from one thing - GPS location seems not to work at all.  I have both GPS and Location switched on, but whenever I go into Google Maps it says it can't establish my precise location.

I'm running UTouch under the Android MultiRom Manager app, and the other 2 OSs are Android Lollipop and CyanogenMod 11; GPS works fine under both of these.  I've tried going outdoors but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  Any ideas - is GPS just not supported?

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: I am running Utouch 14.10 r144 on Nexus 4 and it is working like expected. So GPS is supported.